# How to decrypt the password of ion_auth library in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

Can i decrypt the password of ion_auth library? i am trying to create a change password module, but instead of just updating their password, i am just gonna show them their password as decrypt.

```
password : $2y$08$Zc0AwIMQ/rlc67jK18HNqeGt8i7zZOuTpFzcMhaGzjP5UmUHMENY6
```

```
$salt       = $this->store_salt ? $this->salt() : FALSE;
$password   = $this->hash_password($password, $salt);
```

here is how ion_auth encrypt the post password, but can i reciprocate this to instead of encrypting my password, i will decrypt the password that i have in my database?.

any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: if you can decrypt `password_hash` as used in line 304 here (https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/3/models/Ion_auth_model.php#L304) you should report this bug directly to the php team - short answer: _no you can't_

Comment: Can't be done, it would be a real security problem if you could.